# Matching multiple words in a string

Tags: matlab

My query is `string1 = 'Ram is going to school'` and my other string to match is `query_string = Ram school`. How can I match only these two words to above string. Meaning `query_string` matches to `string1` if and only if both words from `query_string` are in `string1`.

`string1 = 'Ram is going to school'`

`query_string = Ram school`

output = query string has a match

Comment: `string1` is splitted into words and `query_string` is also splitted. Now, how to return result when both words are matched.

Comment: The return value would be a binary right? `1` for perfect match and `0` otherwise?

Comment: Yes! it will be a binary

Comment: So, my answer would work for you, if I understood your question correctly?

Comment: I will try and tell you.

Comment: Can i provide a threshold on the number of words to be matched.

Comment: Yes of course , `out = nnz(ismember(split1,split2))>=Threshold` from my code.

Comment: Just curious if the given answer worked for you?

Comment: can you tell me how to do it with non-case sensitivity.

Comment: Edited my code for that! Look into **Extended Part 2: Case insensitive match**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
string1 = 'Ram is going to school'
query_string = 'Ram school'

split1 = unique(regexp(string1,'\s','Split'),'stable');
split2 = unique(regexp(query_string,'\s','Split'),'stable');

out = nnz(ismember(split1,split2))==numel(split2)
```

**Output**

```
out =    
     1
```

Editing `query_string = 'Ram school days'`, gives `out` as `0`.

**Extended Part 1:** Instead, if you would like to have a threshold on the number of matches, use this -

```
out = nnz(ismember(split1,split2))>=Threshold
```

**Extended Part 2: Case insensitive match**

```
string1 = 'ram is going to schooL';
query_string = 'Ram School';

string1c = unique(regexp(string1,'\s','Split'),'stable');
query_stringc = unique(regexp(query_string,'\s','Split'),'stable');

lstring1c = cellfun(@lower,string1c,'uni',0);
lquery_stringc = cellfun(@lower,query_stringc,'uni',0);

out = nnz(ismember(lstring1c,lquery_stringc))==numel(query_stringc)
```

**Output**

```
out =

     1
```